# SELF JOIN to get distinct rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I've a table with a column `type` ENUM('A', 'B'), `parent`, `score`, `userid`

All the rows with type `A` has parent(foreign key) while `B` has parent of type `A`(id)

| id | type | parent | score | userid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | fk | 1 | u1 |
| 2 | A | fk | 5 | u1 |
| 3 | B | 1 | 2 | u1 |
| 4 | B | 2 | 4 | u2 |
| 5 | B | 2 | 2 | u1 |
| 6 | A | fk | 4 | uz |

Now, I want to select all those rows of A whose child(i.e. type `B`) are `not` of userid u1.

Query I tried:

```
select distinct A.id from tableName as A
 LEFT JOIN tableName as B
 ON A.id = B.parent
 WHERE A.type = 'A'
 AND (B.parent is null or B.user_id != 'u1')
```

With this query, able to get all the records which do not have any child(type `B`); However, cases like `id=4` appears, whose `user_id` is `u2`, which is not expected as `parent=2` is also shared by `id=5`.

Current Result:

| id | type | parent | score | userid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | fk | 5 | u1 |
| 6 | A | fk | 4 | uz |

Expected:

| id | type | parent | score | userid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | A | fk | 4 | uz |

Although this can be done with inner query, however, my table size is very huge and inner doesn't looks like a good solution. Is there any way this can be done with joins only.

Comment: So parent column is a string? or when you have fk here is it actually null in the table?

Comment: Yes, it's a string. Have modified the query, that was something I tried with right join.

Comment: @forpas Apologies. In a hurry I made some mistakes in the question. Have fixed it. It is the final version which I've tried. Can test it on the same fiddle.
https://dbfiddle.uk/DP08rh4-

Comment: You will be able to meaningfully improve performance by changing the `fk` connection to use `NULL`, or `0`, or `-1`, or some value like that, so that you can convert this to an integer column.

Comment: I would have made a separate table altogether if that was an option. The column couldn't be changed, at least for next few months.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn -- he could also make a calculated integer column and put an index on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.type = 'A'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM tablename t2
            WHERE t2.parent = t1.id AND t2.user_id = 'u1'
          );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gKtYUsdD).

Comment: how will be the performance for inner query given the huge size of table?

Comment: @MarkhorKiller EXISTS usually performs better than a join because it does not have to scan the full table but returns as soon as it finds a match. Also, indexes would help. You need an index on type and a composite index on parent, user_id. In any case you have to try the code with your actual data.

Comment: yes, already have indexes placed on the relevant columns. giving it some try. So, far looks good.